# ways to select a non-empty subset of these people, such that no two adjacent people are selected.

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, puzzle, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have asked this question before
[**Here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415717/find-the-total-number-of-ways-to-select-a-non-empty-subset-of-these-people-such)
The first guy solved it in a way, but 
i would like to know is there any efficient way
to do so, because i did the same for N = 13 and N = 15 
which took long time.

This problem is from a pen and paper test, ZIO-2018
Can i solve it with an efficient algorithm,
well i am pretty beginner in algos, so if there is one kindly descibe it how can i do so?

Thank you

Comment: The second answer with the recurrence relation could be quickly computed on pencil and paper. But it appears you didn't fully understand that solution, so perhaps that should be your question.

Comment: yes,can you explain me here

Comment: Can you pinpoint which part you don't understand (Step 1 or Step 2)?

Comment: I dont understand how to apply the formula and what he said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will quote [Matthew Daly's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3415748/255727) and try to provide additional explanation. I will also make a small change.

> Let $C_n$ be the number of ways to choose a **[nonempty]** group of people from a circle of $n$ people such that no two adjacent people are chosen, and let $L_n$ be the number of ways to choose a **[possibly empty]** group of people from a line of $n$ people such that no two adjacent people are chosen. <s>For now, we will include the possibility that no one in the group is chosen -- remind me to rule that out at the end, okay?</s>

The number $C_n$ is the number you are looking for. We'll see soon why we also want to consider $L_n$, which is defined similarly but for people standing in a line rather than a circle (i.e., there are two people at the ends of the line, and those people are not considered adjacent to one another). Note that $C_n$ does *not* count the empty group, but $L_n$ does.

> **Step 1:** $C_n=(L_{n−1} -1)+L_{n−3}$
>
> Proof: Let $n$ people numbered $p_1$ through $p_n$ be in a circle. Either $p_n$ is in the group or not. If $p_n$ is not in the group, then the remaining people could be selected for a group in $L_{n−1}$ ways.

We are breaking down all of the choices that make up $C_n$ into two categories: those that do not include the person $p_n$ and those that do. Suppose we know that $p_n$ is not selected. Then if we remove $p_n$ from the circle, we are left with a line of $n-1$ people: $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_{n-1}$. It is a line rather than a circle since the two people on either side of $p_n$ (i.e., $p_1 $ and $p_{n-1}$) are not adjacent to each other ($p_n$ was between them). So the number of ways to choose a (possibly empty) group of people *not* including $p_n$ and such that no two people are adjacent is $L_{n-1}$, the number of ways to choose a (possibly empty) group of people from the line of $n-1$ people such that no two are adjacent. However, this counts the choice of the empty group from the circle, so we subtract one to get $(L_{n-1}-1)$ as the number of *nonempty* groups which do not include $p_n$.

> If $p_n$ is in the group, then we know for certain that $p_{n−1}$ and $p_1$ cannot be in the group, so the remaining members of the group can be chosen in $L_{n−3}$ ways.

Now we are counting how many groups do contain $p_n$. Since their neighbors ($p_1$ and $p_{n-1}$) cannot be in the group, we remove them along with $p_n$ and get the line of $n-3$ people: $p_2,p_3,\dots,p_{n-2}$. We need to choose the remainder of the group from this line such that no two people are adjacent to each other. The number of such choices is $L_{n-3}$. This time we allow the empty group to be chosen from the line, since the group chosen from the circle contains $p_n$ and thus is not empty. So there are $L_{n-3}$ ways to choose a group containing $p_n$ from the circle such that no two people are adjacent.

Combining these two counts, we now have $C_n$ written in terms of $L_{n-1}$ and $L_{n-3}$, which might not seem like an improvement. But we can try to work out what the $L_n$'s are.

> **Step 2:** $L_n=F_{n+2}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$'th Fibonacci number (i.e. $L_1=2$,$L_2=3$)

The Fibonacci numbers are defined by $F_1 = 1, F_2=1$ and for all $n >2$, $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$. (So $F_3=F_1+F_2=1+1=2$, $F_4=F_2+F_3=1+2=3$, $F_5=F_3+F_4=2+3=5$, and so on). So to prove the claim in Step 2, it suffices to show that $L_1=F_3$, $L_2=F_4$, and for all $n >2$, $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$.

> Proof: By inspection, $L_1=2$ and $L_2=3$, since we are still counting the possibility that no one is chosen.

To be explicit, the choices when the line is just $p_1$ are $\emptyset$ and $\{p_1\}$. The choices when the line consists of $p_1,p_2$ are $\emptyset$, $\{p_1\}$, and $\{p_2\}$. Now we show $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$ for $n >2$:

> Let $n>2$ be given, and let $p_1$ through $p_n$ be our $n$ people in a line. Again, either $p_n$ is in the group or not. If not, then the remaining members of the group can be chosen in $L_{n−1}$ ways.

Again we break down $L_n$ depending on whether $p_n$ is chosen or not. If $p_n$ is not chosen, then removing $p_n$ from the line leaves $p_1,\dots,p_{n-1}$ which is a line of $n-1$ people. So the number of ways to choose a group from this line such that no two people are adjacent is $L_{n-1}$.

> If so, then $p_{n−1}$ must not be in the group and the remaining members can be chosen in $L_{n−2}$ ways.

If $p_n$ is chosen, then we know their neighbors $p_{n-1}$ cannot be chosen. Removing these two individuals leaves the line $p_1,\dots,p_{n-2}$ which is a line of $n-2$ people. So there are $L_{n-2}$ ways to choose a group from this line such that no two people are adjacent.

> Therefore, $L_n=L_{n−1}+L_{n−2}$ and the sequence is a tail of the Fibonacci sequence starting at $2$.

This is just combining the two counts depending on whether $p_n$ is chosen or not. This ends the proof of Step 2.

The purpose of Step 2 was to get an explicit expression for the $L_n$'s so that we can plug those in to the expression in Step 1. Doing this, we get
$$C_n=(L_{n-1}-1)+L_{n-3} = (F_{n+1}-1) + F_{n-1}.$$

To work this out by hand for, say, $n=15$, you need to compute $F_{14}$ and $F_{16}$. This can be done by repeated addition starting with what I began calculating above:

\begin{align*}
F_1&=1\\
F_2&=1\\
F_3&=2\\
F_4&=3 \\
F_5&=5\\
F_6&=3+5=8\\
F_7&=5+8=13\\
F_8&=8+13=21\\
F_9&=13+21=34\\
F_{10}&=21+34=55\\
F_{11}&=34+55=89\\
F_{12}&=55+89=144\\
F_{13}&=89+144=233\\
F_{14}&=144+233=377\\
F_{15}&=233+377=610\\
F_{16}&=377+610=987.
\end{align*}

So $C_{15}=(F_{16}-1)+F_{14} = (987-1)+377=1363$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't understand this link **If pn is chosen, then we know their neighbors pn−1 cannot be chosen....... **   
the neighbour of **Pn** is Pn-1 only (in a line), and in circle **P1 andPn-1**
why are you removing two individuals **Pn and Pn-1** ?

and, rest i understood everything.

Comment: We are assuming that $p_n$ is chosen to be in the group, so when we are choosing the *remainder* of the group, then we cannot choose $p_n$ (they are already chosen) or their neighbor(s).

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for counting the number of qualifying subsets of size $m$ is $\frac{n}{n-m}\binom{n-m}{m}$, so you need the sum for all $m$ up to $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$

Comment: I apologize in advance for not providing a link to a question where that formula is explained. I am on mobile and had some difficulty finding what I was looking for.

Comment: can you explain how to apply this formula to get the answer , for let say
N = 11 ,