# Finding the subsets of people sitting around a circular tables

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

[image]
[image]

Hello community! The problem you see above is a combinatorial problem that I could not solve. :c

This problem seemed easy to me at first like there are people $1,2,3, \ldots, n$ sitting on a circular table and I thought that it was easy using casework and stuff. However, when I really started doing this problem, this problem seemed harder than I thought. I thought about complementary counting but that clearly won't help. From the example given above, I tried first adding singleton sets: $n$. But how do I find out the number of sets with two elements and so on? Recursion?? I really don't know.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: (1) As a courtesy to others, you need to mention the **source**, e.g. that this is from  https://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2019/zio2019/zio2019-question-paper.pdf -- especially for a contest problem, if you mention it's a past contest, people are more willing to help.  (2) This question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416366/ways-to-select-a-non-empty-subset-of-these-people-such-that-no-two-adjacent-peo/3416456#3416456) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415717/find-the-total-number-of-ways-to-select-a-non-empty-subset-of-these-people-such)

Comment: Thank you so much antkam for the solution!